# 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) on running django rest framework with EC2 along with gunicorn, nginx and Supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

So I hosted my django rest framework project on AWS EC2. I integrated nginx, gunicorn and Supervisor along with it. After it shows successful configuration, the only link that works is the default one. Example http://35.154.109.114/ works but any other URL say http://35.154.109.114/test isn't working How ever these links work when I use a standard gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 DemoProject.wsgi:application command. Please let me know how to work this out.
my main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import URL
from django.views.static import serve



urlpatterns = [

url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('main.urls')),
path('', include('poultryapp.urls')),
path('', include('Vet.urls')),
path('', include('call_module.urls')),
path('', include('payment.urls')),
path('', include('adminApp.urls')),
path('', include('community.urls')),
path('', include('sdk.urls')),
path('', include('cooperative.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

the nginx config file I edited after giving the sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default command:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 35.154.109.114/;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/api.drpashu/app.sock;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /var/www/html/api.drpashu/static/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #       
            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}
}

if it helps to understand better, I used [these](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UZkyBG3TLgO1GHlXB4NUGt2SPrMasNSS/view) set of instructions. I did everything as mentioned exactly same, except changing database to mySQL.

Comment: Can you add your main `urls.py` as well as nginx configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to proxy pass to the running gunicorn service that supervisord is running. `proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8000;`. Right now you aren't pointing at the gunicorn service it looks like. I would also strongly recommend turning on logging for your nginx server so you can more easily trouble shoot these kinds of issues too.

```
access_log   /var/log/nginx/some_site.access.log;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/some_site.error.log;
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://some_server_def;
        break;
    }
}
```